# Run python script that imports local script in a docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a local script `main.py` that imports another local script `submain.py`. When I run it in a docker I get the following error:

```
qsub -cwd -soft -l docker,docker_images="*docker_imagename*" -S /usr/bin/python ./main.py --arg1 value1 --arg2 value2

from submain import func
ImportError: No module named submain
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install build-essential libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev python-dev python-pip pkg-config libffi-dev libcairo-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install python-igraph scikit-learn numpy scipy matplotlib

CMD /usr/local/bin/igraph
```

How can I run my script main.py with additional script stored locally? If this not possible, how I "attach" submain.py to docker image?

Comment: Can you add some more information? In particular, at least the docker command you're running. Also, this works when you run igraph locally (not in docker)? Also why is it running qsub?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that I'm working on a remote machine (for which I don't have sudo permissions, hence no igraph locally). I use qsub to submit a job to another server and I don't run any docker command except the one I specified. It worked for the scripts when there is no imports of local scripts happening, however, in this case it does not know where to look for submain.py.

Comment: If we forget about the fact that I'm launching via qsub, what would be the command/Dockerfile to run the script via docker command?

Comment: Why not just `COPY` your python files into the Dockerfile?

Comment: Are you sure you're running docker at all? I'm not familiar with qsub but I think maybe it's copying main.py to the remote server and running it directly (without docker, and also without copying submain.py). Is that possible? (To answer your question, something like `docker run dockerimagename`, also with the previous suggestion to add COPY directives to get the files in, and a different CMD.)

Comment: What docker commands are you using to get this result? Also, try to collate dependent RUN commands into one RUN. This makes it so you don't get cache problems. I would read the best practices about RUN.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example of how this works, with docker + python (ignoring qsub).

First, main.py:

```
from submain import my_fn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('got val {} from submain.my_fn'.format(my_fn(12)))
```

And submain.py:

```
def my_fn(val):
    return val * 2
```

And the Dockerfile [1]:

```
FROM python:3

COPY main.py main.py
COPY submain.py submain.py

ENTRYPOINT python main.py
```

Then to test it:

```
$ docker build -t main-py-img .
# ... lots of output ...
Successfully built e79194e43094
Successfully tagged main-py-img:latest
$ docker run main-py-img
```

If possible, you should try to test this on a local environment, to work out the python + docker issues, before you move to submitting a job with qsub. Using qsub to submit a job that runs your docker image is a different issue -- probably you should create a new question about that, once you get this part resolved.

[1] For simplicity I've inherited from the `python:3` docker image, to avoid having to install all the python dependencies. If for some reason you need Ubuntu, you can try with that instead. In case you don't need Ubuntu, you can just add `RUN pip install igraph` to the Dockerfile above (inherit from `python:2` if you need python 2 instead of python 3), but I would recommend to start with the most minimal example possible, and build from there.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to

> How can I run my script main.py with additional script stored locally?

Python will try to load a module using its libraries path and current dir. So, since you seem to be using /root/ as main folder, you could add this line to a docker run execution (I don't have experience with qsub):

```
-v /local/path/to/submain.py:/root/submain.py
```

It will map container's /root/submain.py to your local submain.py. So you don't need to copy your submain file to the docker image.

Mind that you are running your scripts as root inside a container. So any volume or data that the container can write/read could be exposed if you run any insecure service.

It's also a good idea to check [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) and [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) Dockerfile options.

In answer to

> If this not possible, how I "attach" submain.py to docker image?

using this inside the `Dockerfile` will do the trick:

```
COPY submain.py submain.py
```

Mind that you must build a new image before every in-container testing or use a volume as in previous example before sending it to the grid.